# Pass array to Redshift parametrized insertion

Tags: odbc, amazon-redshift

I have the following Redshift query executed via ODBC / C++:

```
INSERT INTO _tmp_limit_0(val) VALUES(?);
```

_tmp_limit_0 is a temporary table.

I want to bind an string array to the ? parameter with SQLBindParameter to insert multiple rows in one statement.

The problem is if I query the rows in the table, it seems, that only 1 row has been inserted:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM _tmp_limit_0;
```

Can anybody help me, what did I wrong? How can I insert multiple rows in one query using SQL (the solution should work across multiple relational DB)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each row's data needs to be within parentheses separated with commas.  Like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(val) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

If you want to insert multiple columns of data in multiple rows then the column information is comma separated within the parentheses.  Like:

```
INSERT INTO table(val1, val2) VALUES (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7);
```

See - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html